# Разница между ASP.NET Core и ASP.NET MVC и ASP.NET Core MVC и ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp

В чем разница между ASP.NET Core и .NET Core и ASP.NET? Очень хочу получить подробный и полный ответ. (Объясните разницу между **всеми** этими технологиями - между каждыми двумя из приведенных)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если совсем коротко, то есть две платформы:

- .NET Framework. Только под Windows, версии от 1 до 4.8. Последний релиз 18 Апреля 2019, Дальше не развивается. Из преимуществ - до недавнего времени только на ней можно было писать и десктопные приложения для Windows.
- .NET Core - кроссплатформенная (Windows/Mac/Linux), Версии 1-3, 5, 6. Активно развивается, текущая версия - 5, почти 6. В нумерации версий пропущена 4, чтобы не путать с  одновременно существующими версиями .NET Framework. С 3-й версии поддерживает в том числе и десктопные приложения под Windows.

[По заявлению MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five), .NET Core, начиная с версии 5 - единая платформа, переименована просто в .NET 5, все остальное (включая .NET Framework 4.8) - легаси.

Так что если вы решили учить .NET - используйте .NET 5.

---

C ASP.NET та же история:

- ASP.NET - библиотеки .NET Framework для разработки под web.
- ASP.NET MVC - библиотеки .NET Framework для разработки под web с использованием паттерна MVC.
- ASP.NET Core 5.0 - библиотеки .NET 5 для разработки под web (в том числе и с использованием MVC)

В названии ASP.NET Core 5.0 оставили слово Core, т.к. последняя версия ASP.NET MVC (не Core) под .NET Framework имела версию 5 - хотели избежать еще большей путаницы.

---

Соответственно, текущий стек под веб - это .NET 5 + ASP.NET Core 5

Comment: Спасибо, Вы изложили всё кратко и по существу. Проголосовал за Ваш ответ. Оставил свой, так как он содержит историческую шелуху.

Comment: @S.H. историческая шелуха - это интересно! :)

Answer (score 11):

В вопросе сложность в том, что перечисленное нужно сравнивать не по одному какому то параметру.

Вы своим вопросом подразумеваете, что это - штуки, котрые относятся к одному "классу технологий" и которые в силу этого можно легко сравнить.

Чтобы в этом разобраться, надо окунуться в прошлое.

Сначала была ASP. Это была такая "слегка подправленная php-шечка от Microsoft", где в ходу было смешение html и кода, но уже была строгая типизация и возможность подключения COM-компонентов.

Это открывало широкие возможности для постороения сайтов с активным содержимым по технологии server-side, потому что JS в этот момент находился в зачаточном состоянии хорошо подходил только для рисования снежинок на главной странице в период с декабря по март.

Потом, так как абрревиатура ASP уже была известна аудитории (а Microsoft вообще очень любит трехбуквенные абревиатуры) появилась ASP.NET

Это был огромный шаг вперед, который позволил применять возможности NET Framework на серверной стороне WEB сайтов. Под "возможности" здесь подразумеваются возможности языков (C#, VB.NET, и, кажется, F# - и все они КОМПИЛИРОВАЛИСЬ в промежуточный байт-код, котрый выполнялся  при помощи NET runtime). Но, так как NET Framework (версий 1, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 4.51, 4.52, 4.6, 4.7 и 4.8) был только под винду, он был гвоздями прибит к IIS и Microsoft Server, что, конечно же, вызывало иронические усмешки у всех бородатых линукс-админов.

Одновременно появилась ASP.NET MVC, что обозначало применение шаблона Model-View-Сontroller в ASP.NET. Фактически, вместо беспорядочно сгруппированного кода, предлагалось разделить код на сущности, относящиеся к Model, View или Controller.

Для того, чтобы стать кроссплатформенной, была рождена .NET Core. Которая одинаково работает как на винде, так и на линуксе. Это огромный фреймворк, по масштабу сопоставимый с Spring'ом из мира Java. Его часть, имеющая отношение к WEB, названа ASP.NET Core. В ней была возможность применения шаблона MVC, и именно это, скорее всего, подразумевается под ASP.NET Core MVC.

В силу того, что писать много аббреиатур подряд скучно, названия стали сокращать, например, с ASP.NET Core MVC до .NET Core MVC, и вообще - кто во что горазд.

Фактически, в .NET Core есть:

.NET Core - весь фреймворк.

ASP.NET Core - часть фреймворка, заточенная под WEB.

ASP.NET Core MVC - часть фреймворка, заточенная под WEB, в которой применен шаблон MVC

Поэтому, возвращаясь к вопросу, при сравнении нужно пользоваться такой схемой:

0. В названии технологии есть ASP или ASP.NET? Если да - значит, эта технология имеет отношение к WEB. Если просто "ASP" - скорее всего, .NET просто "забыли дописать", потому что технология ASP очень древняя и сейчас уже не применяется.
1. В названии технологии есть Core? Если да - то технология кросспалтформенная и основана на фреймворке .NET Core. Если в названии технологии есть Framework или просто слово Core отсутствует - скорее всего, имеется в виду фреймворк NET Framefork, работающий только под Windows
2. В названии технологии есть MVC? Если да - то применяется шаблон разделения на Model-View-Controller, если нет - обходятся как то без этого. Или сократили часть аббревиатуры, посчитав, что все и так догадаются.

Таким образом, ответ на Ваш *текущий* вопрос (а до редактиования вопроса у Вас упоминалось еще использование шаблона MVC) такой:

```
| Название технологии   | WEB или общего назначения?  |  Кроссплатформенная?  |
|                       |                             |                       |
| ASP.NET Core          | WEB                         |  да                   |
|                       |                             |                       |
| .NET Core             | общего назначения           |  да                   |
|                       |                             |                       |
| ASP.NET?              | WEB                         |  нет, только Windows  |
```

Так стало понятнее?

Comment: из вашего ответа следует, что `NET` - весь фреймворк, а `ASP.NET Core` и `.NET Core` (что одно и тоже - 2-е сокращение 1-го) - это часть фреймворка, заточенная под WEB.

Comment: @gitfront - справедливое замечание, сейчас исправлю!

Comment: @gitfront, пожалуйста, выведите меня на чистую воду... Вот есть NET Core. Это - именно что весь фреймворк, который, к примеру, позволяет писать простые console app. И мне кажется, что ASP.NET Core - это его подмножество. Например, потому, что в доках у MS есть разные статьи "Get started with .NET Core" и "Get started with ASP.NET Core". Не могли бы Вы проверить, прав я или нет? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/

Comment: > Из вашего ответа следует, что NET - весь фреймворк, а ASP.NET Core и .NET Core (что одно и тоже - 2-е сокращение 1-го) - это часть фреймворка, заточенная под WEB. NET - это традиционное сокращение от NET Framework. То есть, NET без кроссплатформенности. NET Core - это ДРУГОЙ (кроссплатформенный) фреймворк.  ASP.NET Core - это часть этого другого фреймворка, предназначенная для WEB разработки. Если я не прав - я буду рад обоснованной критике.

Comment: я плохо знаком с С# - поэтому подтяните кого-то кто работал с этими технологиями. Как увеличить посещаемость вопроса?

Comment: я работал :-) Я научусь рисовать таблицы и напишу вам срвнение Ваших 4 аббреваитур по трем параметрам:  "для WEB или общего назначения" "кроссплатформенность" и "MVC-шность". Хотя уже сейчас Вы можете воспользоваться шпаргалкой из трех пунктов в конце моего ответа

Comment: я имел виду как увеличить посещаемость вопроса (чтобы больше человек увидели вопрос)?

Comment: @gitfront > я имел виду как увеличить посещаемость вопроса (чтобы больше человек увидели вопрос)? - можно объявить вопрос "конкурсным". К таким вопросам внимания больше. Но, кажется, для этого нужен немного бОльший уровень репутации. Еще можно добавлять в вопрос более популярные метки. Но это уже на грани соблюдения правил сайта.

Comment: MVC - это паттерн. ну или шаблон.

Comment: @PashaPash - да, но, кажется, я как раз в последнем исправлении своего ответа везде всё поправил на "шаблон"