# Отличие платформы от библиотеки

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, библиотеки

На [Разница между ASP.NET Core и ASP.NET MVC и ASP.NET Core MVC и ASP.NET](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325059/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-asp-net-core-%d0%b8-asp-net-mvc-%d0%b8-asp-net-core-mvc-%d0%b8-asp-net#1325070) были упомянуты платформы .NET и .NET Core и библиотеки ASP.NET и ASP.NET Core 5.0? В чем отличие платформы от библиотеки?

Comment: Платформа - это набор библиотек.

Comment: Платформа - это набор библиотек + языков програмирования + компиляторов для того, чтобы эти библиотеки создавать. .

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet